# Android Google Pay Integration

Tags: android, payment-gateway, google-pay

In the google pay API one needs to mention the gateway for tokenization for payment details.

```
tokenizationSpecification: {
      type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
      gateway: 'example',
      gatewayMerchantId: 'exampleGatewayMerchantId',
    }
```

So do I first need to buy a supported [payment gateway](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/#participating-google-pay-processors)? If so, why won't I accept payments from the gateway itself rather than from GPAY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So do I first need to buy a supported payment gateway?

Yes, you need to sign up with a supported payment gateway. The reason for this is because Google Pay doesn't process payments, it facilitates it. What I mean by that is it provides you (the merchant) with a secure method of sharing a customer's payment details (through Google Pay) with a payment gateway for processing. In this setup, only saved payment details are only known to Google and the payment gateway.

> If so, why won't I accept payments from the gateway itself rather than from GPAY.

The reason that you should consider using Google Pay is that entering payment and contact details can be difficult on a mobile device. Giving your customers access to re-use information that they have already saved on their device makes it easy and convenient for them to complete their purchase which reduces the chances of them from dropping out.

Answer (score 0):

"So do I first need to buy a supported payment gateway? If so, why won't I accept payments from the gateway itself rather than from GPAY."

Not true.. what you need is to setup your account on Google Pay Merchant Account, from there you can get the parameters you need for your development

Comment: I have setup payment profile and I have got the merchant id and there is no such thing as   merchant name or gateway